# Authorizing to Kubernetes on Google Container Engine without gcloud SDK from Jenkins

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to setup a continuous integration job that will deploy to kubernetes / google container engine from a Jenkins job. The jenkins server is relatively tightly controlled, so I'm not able to install plugins.

I have a JSON key file for a server account from Google Cloud IAM.

I'm currently trying to download the google cloud sdk and auth from there, but am not having any luck (this if from a Jenkinsfile):

```
sh 'export KUBECONFIG=$(pwd)/.kubeconfig'
sh 'export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$JSON'
sh 'google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=$JSON'
sh 'google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config set core/project proj-1'
sh 'google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud container clusters list'
sh 'google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud container clusters get-credentials clust-1 --zone us-east1-c'
sh 'kubectl get pods'
```

I'm getting the error message:
error: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
I will also need to be able to do a gcloud docker push, so using gcloud is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a cryptic github issue around this behavior:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30617

According to that issue, everything I've been doing should work:

> Previously, gcloud would have configured kubectl to use the cluster's static client certificate to authenticate. Now, gcloud is configuring kubectl to use the service account's credentials.
>
> Kubectl is just using the Application Default Credentials library, and it looks like this is part of the ADC flow for using a JSON-key service account. I'll see if there is a way that we could make this nicer.
>
> If you don't want to add the export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/keyfile.json" to your flow, you can reenable the old way (use the client cert) by setting the cloudsdk container/use_client_certificate property to true. Either:
>
> gcloud config set container/use_client_certificate True
>
> or
>
> export CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_USE_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE=True

I was using the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable, but alas, was not working. I tried the "gcloud config set" option up above, but that also didn't work. Finally, I used the env variable CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_USE_CLIENT_CERTIFCIATE and that actually finally did work.